# Deployment schema problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I have changed my app name and namespaces as well from FooXXX to FooYYY.
VS applied changes to all files. I've checked all namespaces, names etc, project compiles but when I want to deploy it to emulator or to a device it crashes straight away. No warring, no message, no exception. Only spash screen is shown and then OS gets back to start screen.

I made a copy of this solution and I've changed all names, namspaces again and now app compiles and deploys, but I have two messages:

Message 2   Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment:Deployment.Parts'.

Message 1   Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment:Deployment'.

Any clue what casuses the crash?

Comment: No code is reached like Application_UnhandledException. Just thread 'NO-Name' return 0 after loading all sys dll.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the "Startup Object" in the project properties page. The sometimes requires manually being set/corrected when the namespace of the app is changed.

Comment: Awesome! you are the best Matt ;)

Comment: I spent hours to figure out the problem, then finally I found your answer. Shouldn't Visual Studio throw an Error or Warning for missing Startup Object? Also, when renaming with refactor, it should also replace the code in XML configuation files! I hope the next release (VS11) would be more content-aware in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but it was due to the WCF RIA Services link.

1. In the project properties change the WCF RIA Services link to
2. Save and close the tab
3. Change to the previous link
4. Save

Answer (score 1):

I got a problem like this and it was a problem inside WMAppManifest.xml file under Properties. Look at the TokenId, default page etc...

Comment: I copy paste this :/ can i regenerate this?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I actually just restarted VS2012.

Comment: It works for you because the project  you want to compile is probably the first one in the visual solution list. In other way it wouldn't work. Please review @Matt Lacey answer.